# catkin install scripts with symlink

Tags: ros, catkin-install

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When a package has scripts (either in `src/` or in `scripts/`) `catkin_make install` can copy those scripts into a install location so that they can be `rosrun`able. (This is done at the bottom of http://wiki.ros.org/rospy_tutorials/Tutorials/Makefile)

Is there an equivalent to `python setup.py develop` or `pip install --editable` that allows the original script to be edited and immediately run, without needing to do `catkin_make install`? This would require, for example, not copying the script but making a symlink.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287830/catkin-install-scripts-with-symlink/) by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2018-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will sounds 'strange', but just don't run `catkin_make install`. Catkin only installs things when you ask it to. In a non-install run, it will compile things that need to be compiled (ie: C++, other languages), copy the output to the `devel` space, but Python modules and scripts are actually (almost) untouched.

It then places the path to the package containing the Python module(s) and script(s) in the `src` space on the `PYTHONPATH` and `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and after you `source $CATKIN_WS/devel/setup.bash` you should be able to run everything. The `install` space is actually not needed for that.

You end up with a situation that is analogous to `setup.py develop` (analogous, not identical): just edit the files in your `src`space and after having run `catkin_make` the first time, you don't need to do it again.

Unless you add or remove packages, or msg, service or action definitions, or any other part of packages that require code generation or building of some form.

---

Edit:

> If I have a `catkin_install_python`, then I can `rosrun mypkg myscript`, otherwise `myscript` isn't available to `rosrun`.

I don't know about `catkin_install_python`, but `rosrun` will only show and start executable files. I've had this problem when forgetting to make my scripts executable.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on 2018-04-07**:
Thanks for your answer. I suppose then I am missing something in `CMakeLists.txt`. If I have a `catkin_install_python`, then I can `rosrun mypkg myscript`, otherwise `myscript` isn't available to `rosrun`. Also I think I need `catkin_make install` for an unrelated reason.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-08**:
If you must run `catkin_make install`, then you can't exploit the `devel` space as I wrote above unfortunately (or, not immediately: workspace overlaying could be used to work around this).